# Postgres error updating column data

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

Trying to run a update script on a table, but getting an error:

> ERROR:  column "ok" does not exist 
>   LINE 2:    SET first_name="ok", last_name="pk", email="ooo", phone="...

```
CREATE TABLE employee (
   employee_id      SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
   first_name       varchar(255)                NOT NULL,
   last_name        varchar(255)                NOT NULL,
   email            varchar(255)                NOT NULL,
   phone            varchar(255)
);


INSERT INTO employee(
            first_name, last_name, email, phone)
    VALUES ('Kyle', 'Belanger', 'kbelanger@ok.com', '(240) 298-4664');


UPDATE "employee"
   SET first_name="ok", last_name="pk", email="ooo", phone="000"
 WHERE employee_id = 1;
```

Comment: `"ok"` is a column name, not a string literal. Please read the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no need to wrap table name in double quote `"employee"`, and use single quotes for column values

```
UPDATE employee   
   SET first_name='ok', last_name='pk', email='ooo', phone='000'
 WHERE employee_id = 1;
```

[See Working Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/93c2a/6)

Answer (score 1):

Try below sql:

```
 UPDATE employee
   SET first_name='ok', last_name='pk', email='ooo', phone='000'
 WHERE employee_id = 1;
```

Table name was wrapped in double quotes which is not allowed.

Comment: even column values also need single quote only, not double quotes

Comment: I am not sure about it but the above query worked in `sql fiddle`.

Comment: see this , SQL fiddle for your query    http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/93c2a/10.  Share your fiddle which is working?

Comment: I changed it. I did ran it with single quote in sql fiddle. Thanks for pointing it out. (up-vote for your suggestion :) )