# Postgres column doesn't exist error on update

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to run the query below but I am getting an error **ERROR:  column "test.pdf" does not exist** . I dont know why I am getting this error. I search for various links on stackover but none solved my problem like this [PostgreSQL query -- column does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33614625/postgresql-query-column-does-not-exist/33614701), [Postgres error updating column data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30764963/postgres-error-updating-column-data). Please help me find the problem.

bill is a type string field in bills table.

```
update bills 
 set bill = "test.pdf" 
where id=3;
```

Comment: Double quotes are to delineate column names. Use single quotes for strings. I'm voting to close as a simple typographical error.

Comment: Both linked questions describe exactly the same problem as you have

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the double quotes you have around test.pdf to single quotes.